# Applying twig filters in Drupal 8 Views Template

Tags: php, twig, drupal-8

I'm building a themed view in Drupal 8 using twig.  I'd like to use twig filters on the row.content variable in the views-view-unformatted.html.twig template.

It seems that row.content is an array so twig's string manipulation doesn't work. However, it prints onto the page as a string (view is just a list of taxonomy terms).

What I'd like to do is slugify the output so taxonomy terms with spaces can have valid hrefs. See the replace filter in the code below.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
{% for row in rows %}
  <li role="presentation" class="{{loop.first ? 'active' : ''}}">
    <a href="#{{row.content | replace({" ", "-"})}}" aria-controls="{{row.content}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{row.content}}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will just output `<a href="#">`.  Does anyone know how to access the raw text value that is output during twigs interpolation?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do `{{ dump(row.content) }}`? That should give you a list of the values in the array to work with.

Comment: Hi @sjagr.  I did try that, but I was resulting in no data being sent from the server.  I think it causes a memory exception due to circular references in the row.content variable.  Not sure though.

Comment: [Try the other approaches here to see if you can find anything.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906780) Make sure you report back so others can know if you figured it out!

Comment: Ended up not being able to do this an implemented a work-around.  If anyone figures out a good way to do this please let me know!  Would still be really helpful going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this myself it was difficult because kint and dump crashes on views.
there is a quick workaround to get to the bits though, put this under **{% for row in rows %}** in your twig views style template.

```
<ol>
{% for key, value in row.content %}
  <li>{{ key }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

load the page with that & gives you the keys to see, I checked them each with the following dump command, just added underneath to test.

```
{{ dump(row.content['#row']) }}
```

The above dump showed all the goods in #row, where I dug in and found the field I wanted inside _entity (may be different for you), then I wanted to replace spaces with dash and force lowercase.

Everything past **row.content['#row']** is likely different for you, you'll need to dig in the array a bit with the dump command mentioned above. 
Below is the line that got me what I wanted.

```
{{ row.content['#row']._entity.title[0].value|replace(' ', '-')|lower }}
```

Below is twig template example. 
For filename change **viewname** and **block-3** to your setup.

**views-view-unformatted--viewname--block-3.html.twig**

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {%
        set row_classes = [
            default_row_class ? 'views-row',
            'something',
            'kint-cant',
        ]
    %}
    {# My field value unformatted #}
    <!-- {{ row.content['#row']._entity.title[0].value }} --> 

    <section{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }} id="{{ row.content['#row']._entity.title[0].value|replace(' ', '-')|lower }}">
        {{ row.content }}
    </section>
{% endfor %}
```

Im sure there are plenty of other ways to do this, but it worked for me as a quick solution to print out views fields in the style template, which is really useful.

Comment: Shouldnt this question be in the Drupal stackoverflow board?  There are a handful of other questions there similar to this without a working answer.